# lcontain in tcl 8.5.9

Tags: version, tcl

I'm running a program using Tcl 8.5.9, specificly: `/tcl/8.5.9_64/bin/wish8.5` I'm trying to use the `lcontain` command, but the tcl doesn't recognize it. Was it excluded from that version? and is there a different command to replace it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the `lcontain` command checks the existence of an element in a list? This command never was in pure Tcl. It's a part of TclX package, AFAIK.

It the Tcl.8.5 there is `in` operator which can be used in any expressions. For example:

```
set list {A B C D}
set elem "B"
if {$elem in $list} {
    puts "Element '$elem' exists in the list"
}
```

There is also `ni` operator which is opposite to `in` (checks if a list does not contain an element).

In earlier versions of Tcl you can use `lsearch` command and compare the result (index of found element) with `-1` to see whether an element was found actually.

Answer (score 0):

IN many environment where Tcl is present Tclx is loadable via 'package require Tclx'.

```
 -> 8.4
set a {1 2 3 4}
puts [lcontain $a 3]
 -> 1
puts [lcontain $a 5]
 -> 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).